# Por que me sale este error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: android-studio

estoy realizando una app con una base de datos y bueno, la app me funcionaba de hecho tengo 3 filas insertadas y mostradas en la app. Pero de la nada me ha empezado a salir este error:  **java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""** Adjunto código

```
package com.example.petdaycare;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.petdaycare.Data.PetDbHelper;

public class AltaMascotaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name;
    EditText breed;
    EditText gender;
    EditText weight;
    Button btnCreate;
    String nombre = "";
    String raza = "";
    String genero = "";
    int peso = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alta_mascota);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
        breed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRaza);
        gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextGenero);
        weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPeso);
        btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCreate);

        nombre = String.valueOf(name.getText());
        raza = String.valueOf(breed.getText());
        genero = String.valueOf(gender.getText());
        peso = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(weight.getText()));

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callInsertNewPet();
            }
        };
        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);


    }

    public void callInsertNewPet() {
        Pet pet = new Pet (nombre,raza, genero, peso);
        PetDbHelper petDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(this);
        double id = petDbHelper.insertPet(pet);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nueva entrada en la tabla con el ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

El logcat me pone que el responsable del error es esta línea de código:

```
peso = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(weight.getText()));
```

Adjunto una parte del logcat también:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.petdaycare, PID: 4039
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.petdaycare/com.example.petdaycare.AltaMascotaActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
```

No se porque de la nada funcionando antes, ahora me deje de funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que el valor que tratas de convertir de string a int no es numerico, de hecho tratas de convertir una cadena vacia por eso obtienes el error?

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Te sugiero realizar una validación, usando el siguiente método, solo en caso de que el valor no sea numerico entregaría 0.

```
public static int validaInt(String number){
    int result = 0;
    try{
        if(number != null){
            result = Integer.parseInt(number);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Lo usarías de esta forma

```
peso = validaInt(String.valueOf(weight.getText()));
```

Comment: Hola! Pasa que el valor lo recibe cuando el usuario pone algo en el EditText no? O me estoy equivocando. Usare el método que me has dicho a ver si me arregla el error.

Comment: Hola, sucede cuando el valor no es numerico ya que Integer.parseInt(...) convierte una cadena en entero pero si el valor que le proporcionas no es númerico como "", "a",")", "hola", etc se producira el error NumberFormatException ya que solo puede recibir cadenas para convertir valores numericos como "1", "256", "0", etc...

Comment: Vale entiendo porque pasa el error ahora, muchas gracias, el método me ha funcionado así que todo me funciona por ahora bien. De nuevo muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente Ethernal, saludos